# What conditions of clousre are imposed on intervals of a partions by the use of step function when pinching an integrable function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

My questions are at the end.

For simplicity, assume that $f\ge0$ in what follows.

Let $\mathscr{P}_{\mathcal{I}}=\left\{ \mathcal{I}_{i}\right\} _{p}$
be a partition of some interval $\mathcal{Q}\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$
where the intervals $\mathcal{I}_{i}$ may be closed, open, or half
open. Create the step function $h$ on $\mathcal{Q}$

$$
h=\sum_{i=1}^{p}a_{i}\varphi_{i},
$$

where $\left\{ a_{i}\right\} _{p}\subset\mathbb{R}$, and the $\varphi_{i}$
are the characteristic functions of their corresponding intervals.

In the case where intervals $\mathcal{I}_{d}$ and $\mathcal{I}_{e}$
share common boundary points there will be a negligible interval

$$
\mathcal{N}_{de}=\left\{ \mathfrak{x}\vert\mathfrak{x}\in\mathcal{I}_{d}\cap\mathcal{I}_{e}\right\} \ne\emptyset.
$$
On that interval,

$$
\mathfrak{x}\in\mathcal{N}_{de}\implies h\left[\mathfrak{x}\right]=a_{d}+a_{e}.
$$

So there is a "spike" in $h$ where $\mathfrak{x}\in\mathcal{N}_{de}$.
(Or a free-standing wall, if you will.)

If the function $f$ is integrable and $h$ and $k$ are step functions
such that $h\le f\le k$, and the "pinching condition"

$$
\underset{\varepsilon>0}{\forall}0\le\int h\le\int f\le\int k<\varepsilon
$$

holds, then (it seems to me that) the condition where $h\left[\mathfrak{x}\right]=a_{d}+a_{e}$
is precluded in the limit as $\text{mesh}\left[\mathscr{P}_{\mathcal{I}}\right]\to0$.

So the partition supporting the inscribed step fuction, $h$, shall
not have intervals with shared closed faces.

For if $h\left[\mathfrak{x}\right]=a_{d}+a_{e}$ were the case, then
$h$ could not become arbitrarily close to $f$.

This preclusion would not apply to locations where $f\left[\mathfrak{x}\right]=0$.

If one of the intervals, say $\mathcal{I}_{d}$ were closed and the
other, $\mathcal{I}_{e}$ were open; then $\mathfrak{x}\in\mathcal{I}_{d}\cap\partial\mathcal{I}_{e}\implies h\left[\mathfrak{x}\right]=a_{d}$.
This condition would not prevent the "pinching" inequality to
converge.

Similarly, if any pair of intervals of the supporting partition $\mathscr{P}_{\mathcal{J}}=\left\{ \mathcal{J}_{j}\right\} _{q}$
of the circumscribing step function

$$
k=\sum_{j=1}^{q}b_{j}\psi_{j},
$$
were open on their common boundary where $f\left[\mathfrak{x}\right]\ne0$;
then the condition $k\left[\mathfrak{x}\right]=0<f\left[\mathfrak{x}\right]$
would occur. So that must be precluded.

Given a pair of intervals $\mathcal{J}_{s}$ and $\mathcal{J}_{t}$
such that $\mathcal{J}_{s}$ is closed and $\mathcal{J}_{t}$ is open.
Then $\mathfrak{x}\in\mathcal{J}_{s}\cap\partial\mathcal{J}_{t}\implies k\left[\mathfrak{x}\right]=b_{s}$.

If both are closed then $\mathfrak{x}\in\mathcal{J}_{s}\cap\mathcal{J}_{t}\implies k\left[\mathfrak{x}\right]=b_{s}+b_{t}.$
In either case, $k$ will not "fall through" $f$ at that point.

In conclusion; I propose that:

**the intervals $\mathcal{I}_{i}$ of the partion $\mathscr{P}_{\mathcal{I}}$
supporting the inscribing step function $h$ shall not share closed
faces**, and

**the intervals $\mathcal{J}_{j}$ of the partion $\mathscr{P}_{\mathcal{J}}$
supporting the circumscribing step function $k$ shall not share open
faces**.

So first I ask: **are these conditions necessary for the pinching condition
to hold**?

**Are there any circumstances in which the intervals $\mathcal{I}_{i}$
cannot be open?**

**Are there any circumstances in which the intervals $\mathcal{J}_{j}$
cannot be closed?**

**If the answer to both of the last two question is "no", then can
it be assumed that, in any situation where the pinching condition is
being applied as above, the $\mathcal{I}_{i}$ are all open, and the
$\mathcal{J}_{j}$ are all closed?**